# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar datos de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

La petición AJAX mediante, me es dado un objeto JSON con la siguiente estructura:

```
[{
    Nombre: 'Fulano Detal',
    Descripcion: 'Un string explicando a qué se dedica',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
},
{
    Nombre: 'Otro Fulano',
    Descripcion: 'String diferente que tambien describe su trabajo',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
},
{
    Nombre: 'Tercer Fulano',
    Descripcion: 'Su trabajo en donde sea que este',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 2'
}]
```

El array continúa por el estilo llegando a los cerca de 100 objetos con unos 4 o 5 valores de "Ciudad" diferentes.

Mi objetivo es crear un nuevo array de objetos donde cada Ciudad sea representada por un objeto que tenga una propiedad "Nombre" extraída del JSON antes mencionado y una propiedad "Profesionales" que guarde un array de objetos con los profesionales que trabajan dentro de dicha ciudad, obtenido a partir de la iteración sobre el JSON original.

¿Cómo puedo alcanzar ese objetivo con una función JavaScript o jQuery (la librería está implementada en mis páginas, así que no sería un problema emplearla)?

Comment: Te sugiero que le eches un vistazo a esta respuesta que creo que explica cómo podrías lograr tu objetivo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009448/creating-a-json-dynamically-with-each-input-value-using-jquery

Comment: Hola David, ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Muestranos lo que llevas para poderte apoyar.

Comment: Hola muchachos, seguí trabajando en el asunto y finalmente lo resolví, en parte gracias al excelente link que me envió @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia y la resolución de Ángel. Ahora voy a agregar el código que finalmente utilicé en la pregunta original como un edit. Mil gracias a todos por su ayuda!

Comment: No coloques la solución en tu pregunta eso no es válido, lee [answer] y escribela abajo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esta sería otra manera de resolverlo.

```js
var arrayRespuesta = [
    {
         Nombre: 'Fulano Detal',
         Descripcion: 'Un string explicando a qué se dedica',
         Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
    },
    {
        Nombre: 'Otro Fulano',
        Descripcion: 'String diferente que tambien describe su trabajo',
        Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
    },
    {
        Nombre: 'Tercer Fulano',
        Descripcion: 'Su trabajo en donde sea que este',
        Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 2'
    }
]

//Creamos un nuevo objeto donde vamos a almacenar por ciudades. 
let nuevoObjeto = {}
//Recorremos el arreglo 
arrayRespuesta.forEach( x => {
  //Si la ciudad no existe en nuevoObjeto entonces
  //la creamos e inicializamos el arreglo de profesionales. 
  if( !nuevoObjeto.hasOwnProperty(x.Ciudad)){
    nuevoObjeto[x.Ciudad] = {
      profesionales: []
    }
  }
  
  //Agregamos los datos de profesionales. 
    nuevoObjeto[x.Ciudad].profesionales.push({
      nombre: x.Nombre,
      descripcion: x.Descripcion
    })
  
})


console.log(nuevoObjeto)
```

Si tienes control sobre el `arrayRespuesta` y la estructura de datos que te devuelves te recomiendo que no utilices mayúsculas para las propiedades. Comúnmente vas a encontrarte con que se utiliza el camelCase. Solo las clases se ponen en mayúsculas y las instancias y propiedades utilizan el formato. `nombreDeVariable:'dato'`

Comment: Hola Ángel, gracias por tu respuesta. Lamentablemente es un detalle que yo noté, pero estoy interactuando con otro programador y el que controla eso es él, ya que es el emisor del JSON con la información. Bien notado igualmente.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, te respuesta me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 4):

He intentado hacer el código lo más legible posible, espero que te resuelva el problema

Dentro del bucle se pregunta mediante un filtro si ya existe una ciudad dentro del array creado, si existe añade un profesional, sino hace un push con la ciudad y el profesional

```js
     var arrayRespuesta = [
  {
          Nombre: 'Fulano Detal',
          Descripcion: 'Un string explicando a qué se dedica',
          Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
     },
     {
         Nombre: 'Otro Fulano',
         Descripcion: 'String diferente que tambien describe su trabajo',
         Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
     },
     {
         Nombre: 'Tercer Fulano',
         Descripcion: 'Su trabajo en donde sea que este',
         Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 2'
  }
 ]


 var nuevoArray    = []
 var arrayTemporal = []
 for(var i=0; i<arrayRespuesta.length; i++){
     arrayTemporal = nuevoArray.filter(resp => resp["Nombre"] == arrayRespuesta[i]["Ciudad"])
     if(arrayTemporal.length>0){
         nuevoArray[nuevoArray.indexOf(arrayTemporal[0])]["Profesionales"].push(arrayRespuesta[i]["Nombre"])
     }else{
         nuevoArray.push({"Nombre" : arrayRespuesta[i]["Ciudad"] , "Profesionales" : [arrayRespuesta[i]["Nombre"]]})
     }
 }

 console.log(nuevoArray)
```

Comment: Gracias @Gangre!

Answer (score 2):

Existe otra forma para hacerlo, es con la libreria [lodash](https://lodash.com/) es una de las mas populares en el mundo JavaScript, ademas de que tienes otras cosas interesantes

```js
const data = [{
    Nombre: 'Fulano Detal',
    Descripcion: 'Un string explicando a qué se dedica',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
},
{
    Nombre: 'Otro Fulano',
    Descripcion: 'String diferente que tambien describe su trabajo',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
},
{
    Nombre: 'Tercer Fulano',
    Descripcion: 'Su trabajo en donde sea que este',
    Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 2'
}]
const result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("Ciudad")
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente arribé a una solución combinando un par de recursos. En primer lugar, lo que hice fue reorganizar el JSON original, ordenándolo alfabéticamente con la propiedad Ciudad como clave. De este modo, todos los registros de cada ciudad quedaron a continuación unos de otros.

Una vez hecho esto, procedí a elaborar el siguiente código:

```
// "data" es la variable que está alojando el JSON
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    profesional = data[i];

    var ciudadAct;
    var ciudad = {};

    // Revisa si la ciudad que que actualmente estamos leyendo difiere con la última leída
    if (ciudadAct !== profesional.Ciudad) {
        // Guarda la nueva ciudad en la variable correspondiente
        ciudadAct = profesional.Ciudad;

        // Guarda en la propiedad "nombre" del objeto "ciudad" el valor de la propiedad "Ciudad"
        // del profesional que actualmente estamos evaluando
        ciudad.nombre = ciudadAct;

        // Filtra el objeto "data" comparando la propiedad "Ciudad" de cada profesional con la ciudad actual
        ciudad.profesionales = data.filter(profesional => profesional.Ciudad === ciudadAct);

        // Finalmente toma el objeto ciudad con todos los profesionales que le corresponden y lo guarda en el array "ciudades"
        ciudades.push(ciudad);
    }
}
```

La importancia de reordenar los registros reside en que el bloque condicional se ejecutará solamente cuando pasemos del último registro de una ciudad al primero de la siguiente. De esta manera, nos aseguramos de generar un solo objeto por cada ciudad, sin repeticiones.