# Agrupar objetos segun uno de sus campos

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

amigos tengo este objeto json en mi consulta ajax

```
{
    "id": "7",
    "descripcion": "Auditorio Cojab",
    "patio": "OTROS"
},
{
    "id": "19",
    "descripcion": "Cancha de f\u00fatbol",
    "patio": "OTROS"
},
{
    "id": "20",
    "descripcion": "Escalonado K\u00ednder",
    "patio": "OTROS"
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "descripcion": "C4 primaria",
    "patio": "PRIMARIA"
},
{
    "id": "11",
    "descripcion": "Patio de primaria",
    "patio": "PRIMARIA"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "descripcion": "Escenario",
    "patio": "SABA"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "descripcion": "Terraza",
    "patio": "SABA"
}]
```

quisiera mediante alguna funcion en js, agrupar en un objeto independiente cada registro teniendo en cuenta el campo 'patio' de cada uno de ellos, es decir quisiera algo como :

```
[{
    "SABA": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "descripcion": "Terraza"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "descripcion": "Escenario"
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxx",
            "descripcion": "xxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "PRIMARIA": [
        {
            "id": "x",
            "descripcion": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxx",
            "descripcion": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxx",
            "descripcion": "xxxxx"
        }
    ]        
}]
```

no tengo ni idea de como agrupar cada registro de forma independiente en un objeto a parte me podrian ayudar?
he intentado hacerlo con foreachs pero no me ha dado el resutaldo esperado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo logre con la ayuda de esta respuesta 
[aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261457/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-agrupar-datos-de-un-array-de-objetos)

```
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        let aux = {};
        //Recorremos el res 
        res.forEach(x => {
            if (!aux.hasOwnProperty(x.patio)) {
                aux[x.patio] = [];
            } 
            aux[x.patio].push({
                id: x.id,
                descripcion: x.descripcion
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma alternativa usando reduce():

```js
const arr = [{"id": "7","descripcion": "Auditorio Cojab","patio": "OTROS"},{"id": "19","descripcion":"Cancha de f\u00fatbol","patio": "OTROS"},{"id": "20","descripcion": "Escalonado K\u00ednder","patio":"OTROS"},{"id": "17","descripcion":"C4 primaria","patio": "PRIMARIA"},{"id": "11","descripcion": "Patio de primaria","patio": "PRIMARIA"},{"id": "3","descripcion": "Escenario","patio": "SABA"},{"id": "2","descripcion": "Terraza","patio": "SABA"}];

const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  (c.patio in p) ? p[c.patio].push(c): p[c.patio] = [c]
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```