# Invertir clave valor en un objeto

Tags: javascript, poo

Teniendo en cuenta que el objeto original es {a:1,b:2,c:1} necesito invertir las claves valor y agruparlas de este forma. {“1”:[“a”, ”c”], ”2”:[“b”]}

Estaba intentado utilizar el for-in y he conseguido invertirlas, pero no se como puedo agruparlas además.

```js
let objetoInicial = new Object({a:1,b:2,c:1});
let nuevoObjecto = new Object();

for (const key in objetoInicial) {


    nuevoObjecto.objetoInicial[key].push(key) // Esta era mi idea, pero no funciona


    console.log(key);
    console.log(objetoInicial[key]); 


}
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que tienes hasta ahora. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida.

Comment: Pienso que el titulo esta mal en cierta forma porque la palabra correcta a esto es `agrupar`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo agrupar datos de un array de objetos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261457/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-agrupar-datos-de-un-array-de-objetos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con `object.keys` y `reduce`.

```js
let datos = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
}
//Obtenemos las llaves actuales. 
let respuesta = Object.keys(datos)
  .reduce((acumulador, keyAnterior) => {
    //Obtenemos la nueva key deseada. Que es el valor. 
    let nuevaKey = datos[keyAnterior]
    //Si el acumulador no contiene la nueva clave, la creamos y 
    // la inicializamos con un arreglo vacio. 
    if (!acumulador.hasOwnProperty(nuevaKey))
      acumulador[nuevaKey] = []
    //Agregamos la key anterior al arreglo. 
    acumulador[nuevaKey].push(keyAnterior)
    //Retornamos los cambios al acumulador para seguir con el
    //ciclo. 
    return acumulador
  //Este segundo parametro {} es para inicializar el acumulador. 
  //En este caso un objeto. 
  }, {})

console.log(respuesta)
```

> ## [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
>
> El método reduce() ejecuta una función reductora sobre cada elemento de un array, devolviendo como resultado un único valor.

> ## [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)
>
> El método Object.keys() devuelve un array de las propiedades names de un objeto, en el mismo orden como se obtienen en un loop normal.

Tu código estaba cerca de la solución. Implemente la misma respuesta con la estructura que estabas usando.

```js
let objetoInicial = new Object({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
});
let nuevoObjeto = new Object();

for (const key in objetoInicial) {

  //Obtenemos la nueva key deseada. Que es el valor. 
  let nuevaKey = objetoInicial[key]
  //Si el acumulador no contiene la nueva clave, la creamos y 
  // la inicializamos con un arreglo vacio. 
  if (!nuevoObjeto.hasOwnProperty(nuevaKey))
    nuevoObjeto[nuevaKey] = []
  //Agregamos la key anterior al arreglo. 
  nuevoObjeto[nuevaKey].push(key)


}


console.log(nuevoObjeto)
```

Comment: Perfecto, estaba un poco lejos de tu solución. Gracias